# Devise and country_select gem don't save selection into database Rails4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to add country selection in Devise registration and I use country_select gem from https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select#example

There explains the simple usage by using `country_select("user", "country")` use model and attribute as parameters:

**Problem:** When I push submit button user was created and Everything is good except country column doesn't has data from my selection

**Purpose:** After submit registration I want to insert country which I have selected from Signup form into database(table: users, column: country) also

*sign_up.html.erb*

```
<h2><center>Sign up</center></h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
   <%= f.error_notification %>

   <div class="form-inputs" style="float; margin:0 auto;width:35%">
     <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
     <%= f.input :password, required: true %>
     <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
     <%= f.label :country %>

     <%= country_select("user", "country") %>  <<-- My model's name is user.rb and in my users table has a country column

   </div>

   <div class="form-actions" style="float; margin:0 auto;width:10%">
     <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

**My model's name is user.rb and in my users table has a country column

Thanks for advance

Comment: It looks your controller issue. checkout this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471498/adding-extra-registration-fields-with-devise

Comment: @jonsnow I'm following with your link and now I have solved, Should I post the answer of this question

Comment: why not, post it buddy that adds more value to your question. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by following this Question and adapting to my issue [Adding extra registration fields with Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471498/adding-extra-registration-fields-with-devise)

I'm creating override controller(Registrations Controller in this case) for allow Devise to adding country variable to database

1. Create new `registrations_controller.rb`

I have added `:country` in this file

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, :only => [:create]

    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :country) }
    end
end
```

You can see the original registrations_controller.rb at this link: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

2. Create a route to allow Rails can routing to override controller by add these lines
   in `routes.rb`

`devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations' }`

**Important** Please make sure that you don't have any `devise_for :users` line in your `routes.rb`, If you have, delete it

Well, now I can use `<%= country_select("user", "country") %>` to save country selection into database without any problem

Comment: accept the answer so that people know, you've it solved

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
<%= f.input :country, as: :country %>
```