# ArgumentError in Users::RegistrationsController#create '1' is not a valid role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, devise, roles

I am trying to add a drop down menu of User role in a Rails Application. I have configured the devise gem with default parameters. So far I have followed this link to add the user role attribute in User model and the views of Sign up and Log in.
[roles based authetication using enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54698261/roles-based-authetication-using-enum/54705081#54705081?newreg=84291d9b3a2d44f29ec229051c1d9642)

But I am facing an issue. Whenever the sign up operation is performed I get the following error message
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKFJi.png)

In my Users model I have following code

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  enum role: [:manager, :developer, :QA]
end
```

In my view, I have following code for displaying the drop down menu

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :role %><br />
    <%= f.select :role, User.roles %>
  </div>
```

My application controller contains following code

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username, :email, :password, :role])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be more helpful if you uploaded your code, but trying without seeing it.. Do you have host variable set in environment.rb?
Something such as

`config.action_controller.default_url_options = { host: application url' }`

Comment: In environment.rb I just have following content:

# Load the Rails application.
require_relative 'application'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!


After appending your suggested line of code I got the error of "undefined local variable config"

Comment: By the way I have added the related code as well for better improvement

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting a lot finally I was able to get rid of this error by changing my views a bit. The updated views looks like this

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :role %><br />
    <%= f.select :role, ['role#1', 'role#2', 'role#3'] %>
  </div>
```