# use params in devise signup form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, devise

My user visits an item show view and then is send to the signup-page (I use devise). On the signup page, I have the params (item_id) of the item he visited on the previous page. I want this item_id to be saved when the user makes his sign_up (like user.item_id). Here is how I tried to do it:

```
<input value="#{params[:item_id]}" type="hidden" name="user[item_id]" id="user_item_id">
```

When the user is saved, the item_id remains empty. What am I missing here?
Here is what I put into my controller:

```
def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:item_id])
end
```

Comment: how you are redirecting to the signup page, is it by callbacks or something?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I fixed it:

```ruby
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:item_id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How you handling this in controller. Just sending a parameter won't solve your issue

Comment: I edited my inital post with my controller. I got the controller code from this thread that I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42572124/adding-custom-parameters-to-devise-registration-unpermitted-parameters