# How to have strong parameters on devise 'edit' view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-6

I followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42572759/5783745) instructions and now have `time_zone` as a field when the user signs up.

However, the user cannot edit that field, when I try:

```
Unpermitted parameter: :time_zone
```

#### What I know

Since the approach works on /sign_up, I suspect something has to be done to the before_action to allow the `time_zone` parameter to work on other pages. e.g. editing / adding to this:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?


  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:time_zone])
  end
```

That's my best guess, and I'm not sure how to do it if it is correct.

Also, I'm not sure if `:sign_up` is referring to a route, a controller method or something else?

#### Note

- [Devise docs on strong parameters](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#strong-parameters)

#### What I've tried

Attempt 1

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit([:sign_up, :update], keys: [:time_zone])
  end
```

2

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:time_zone])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:update, keys: [:time_zone])
  end
```

3

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:time_zone])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:edit, keys: [:time_zone])
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:time_zone])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:time_zone])
  end
```

That and devise's other methods can be found here: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#strong-parameters