# Attributes not saving with devise and accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an almost working sign up form with Devise. Whilst it seems to work, it's not saving the fields in my `Custaddress` table other than the `user_id`. Any help to work out how to have it save the rest of the information would be great. The following is greatly truncated!!

**User.rb contains:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :custaddress
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :custaddress
end
```

**Custaddress contains:**

```
class Custaddress < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Registrations controller contains:**

As you can see, this just builds on the "standard" Devise controller. There is no create or new here as I assume it's using the standard methods.

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  invisible_captcha only: :create

  protected

  def build_resource(hash = {})
    self.resource = resource_class.new_with_session(hash, session)
    resource.build_custaddress
    # Jumpstart: Skip email confirmation on registration.
    #   Require confirmation when user changes their email only
    resource.skip_confirmation!

    # Registering to accept an invitation should display the invitation on sign up
    if params[:invite] && (invite = AccountInvitation.find_by(token: params[:invite]))
      @account_invitation = invite

    # Build and display account fields in registration form if enabled
    elsif Jumpstart.config.register_with_account?
      account = resource.owned_accounts.first
      account ||= resource.owned_accounts.new
      account.account_users.new(user: resource, admin: true)
    end
  end

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    # Jumpstart: Allow user to edit their profile without password
    resource.update_without_password(params)
  end

  def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    if cookies[:ordernum]
      order = Order.where(ordernum: cookies[:ordernum]).first
      if order
        order.update!(user: resource, custaddress: resource.custaddress)
        cookies.delete "ordernum"
      end
    end

    sign_in(resource_name, resource)

    # If user registered through an invitation, automatically accept it after signing in
    if params[:invite] && (account_invitation = AccountInvitation.find_by(token: params[:invite]))
      account_invitation.accept!(current_user)

      # Clear redirect to account invitation since it's already been accepted
      stored_location_for(:user)
    end
  end
end
```

**My new.html.erb contains:**

```
<%= form_with(model: resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name, invite: params[:invite])) do |f| %>

 <%= f.fields_for :custaddress do |cust| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= cust.label "Apartment/Unit Number", class: "font-bold" %>
        <%= cust.text_field :apartment, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Unit 2 or Apartment 307" %>
      </div>
And much more!
```

**My application controller has:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  include SetCurrentRequestDetails
  include SetLocale
  include Jumpstart::Controller
  include Accounts::SubscriptionStatus
  include Users::NavbarNotifications
  include Users::TimeZone
  include Pagy::Backend
  include CurrentHelper
  include Sortable

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :masquerade_user!
  before_action :store_user_location!, if: :storable_location?

  protected

  # To add extra fields to Devise registration, add the attribute names to `extra_keys`
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    extra_keys = [:avatar, :first_name, :last_name, :time_zone, :preferred_language]
    signup_keys = extra_keys + [:terms_of_service, :invite, owned_accounts_attributes: [:name], custaddress_attributes: [:address, :apartment, :city, :state, :country, :postcode, :mobile]]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: signup_keys)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: extra_keys)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:accept_invitation, keys: extra_keys)
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) || super
  end

  # Helper method for verifying authentication in a before_action, but redirecting to sign up instead of login
  def authenticate_user_with_sign_up!
    unless user_signed_in?
      store_location_for(:user, request.fullpath)
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path, alert: t("create_an_account_first")
    end
  end

  def require_current_account_admin
    unless current_account_admin?
      redirect_to root_path, alert: t("must_be_an_admin")
    end
  end

  private

  def storable_location?
    request.get? && is_navigational_format? && !devise_controller? && !request.xhr?
  end

  def store_user_location!
    # :user is the scope we are authenticating
    store_location_for(:user, request.fullpath)
  end
end
```

My logs are showing:

```
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as JS
17:08:57 web.1     |   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"uVphxW4gCQntvHFxRb33dl9cqxv9vlL69Wc2zOMoF1M+pUk8c2HnHwgQFIkMbfmxYraVI7rYBVCPgfSD1u7OHg==", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"[FILTERED]", "last_name"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "time_zone"=>"Sydney", "custaddress_attributes"=>{"apartment"=>"", "address"=>"XXXXXXXX", "city"=>"XXXXXXX", "state"=>"XXXXX", "postcode"=>"XXXX", "mobile"=>"XXXXXXXX", "country"=>"XXXXXXX"}, "terms_of_service"=>"1"}, "enc-rmjxhdab"=>"", "button"=>""}
```

So, I know it's getting the information from the form. However I have no idea where it's saving the `Custaddress` record. It only seems to be associating the `user_id`:

```
Custaddress Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "custaddresses" ("user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["user_id", 3], ["created_at", "2020-09-25 02:20:39.109187"], ["updated_at", "2020-09-25 02:20:39.109187"]]
12:20:39 web.1     |    (33.9ms)  COMMIT
```

Can anyone please help me work out why the custaddress isn't saving. I've spent hours on this and read every article on google (well it certainly feels like it).

I've tried to track this down, to no avail.

Comment: Can you add the part of the controller that saves/creates the new ``User`` record?

Comment: @rmlockerd I would love to ... if I knew where that was. I have updated the question to hold the whole `RegistrationsController`

Comment: Are you adding the before action `before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?` in your ApplicationController? you are not showing that part of the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42572124/adding-custom-parameters-to-devise-registration-unpermitted-parameters

Comment: @arieljuod thanks for your comment. I've updated the message to show the whole `ApplicationController.` Yes. The `before_action` is there.

Comment: The `create` action calls `build_resource` https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/715192a7709a4c02127afb067e66230061b82cf2/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L17, I would probably start by adding a debugger breakpoint inside your custom `build_resource` method, probably this `resource.build_custaddress` is overriding what's inside params (maybe only call that if `resource.custaddress.nil?`)

Comment: @arieljuod :I did wonder if that was causing the problem ... but if I don't have the `resource.build_custaddress` then none of the fields in the `fields_for` show on the form.

Comment: @Darren that's why I said to call `build_custaddress` ONLY if `custaddress` it's currently nil, don't remove the method call, just make it conditional

Comment: @arieljuod That worked! I have no idea why ... which frustrates me more than I'd like to admit, but your solution has worked. Thank you so much! Hours of my time spent on this.

Comment: @Darren I added an answer for completeness with clarification on what was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an answer for completeness.

Devise's `create` action calls the `build_resurce` method that you are overriding. the problem is that you overrid it for the `new` action but didn't take into account the `create` action.

So, you are doing this:

```rb
  def build_resource(hash = {})
    self.resource = resource_class.new_with_session(hash, session)
    resource.build_custaddress
```

For the `new` action there's no issue, `resource.build_custaddress` will instantiate a new `custaddress` object for you to be able to use the `fields_for` helper.

The problem is that, for the `create` action, at that point `resource` already has a `custaddress` with the values from the request (set by the previous line), then you do `resource.build_custaddress` and replace the current `custaddress` with a new empty one.

The solution is to only build a custaddress if it's not nil:

```rb
  def build_resource(hash = {})
    self.resource = resource_class.new_with_session(hash, session)
    resource.build_custaddress if resource.custaddress.nil?
```

That way you'll have a new empty custaddress for the `new` action, but respect the values from the request for the `create`, `edit` or `update` actions.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Really appreciate the time you put into helping me.