# Confusion regarding custom fields in devise user in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I was studying how to add custom fields in our devise user model in ruby on rails and I came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471498/adding-extra-registration-fields-with-devise) I just have one doubt regarding the following piece of code-

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:email) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :title_id, :province_id, :first_name, :last_name) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end
```

This was written in application controller, In case of :sign_in we only check for email and why not password and in :account_update why don't we check for first_name and last_name after all a user can update his first_name and last_name as well.

Can somebody please help me, How these 3 lines work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sign-in`: The sanitizer knows about Devise default parameters like `password` or `password_confirmation`. Therefore you don't need to add `password` in the list.

`Sign-up/account-update`: You can add `first_name` and`last_name` or change the permitted parameters list on your controllers.

Please See this [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/ParameterSanitizer)

**Note:** Only given parameters will be allowed to process request further.

Comment: Okay, so if I don't put first_name and last_name in `Sign_up` sanitizer then I won't be able to update them?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. The parameters will be ignored if not declared within the `permit` method and won't be inserted into the database.