# undefined method `devise_controllers?'

Tags: devise, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use paperclip 3.5.1 with devise 3.1.0 in a Rails 4 application.

I wanted to be able to add an avatar for my User devise model, so I generated the required fields but I have problem in the showing and saving the picture.

I tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17758341/1221734) but when I try to load a url now I get for every controller that I have the following error. It even appears for the RegistrationController.

```
undefined method `devise_controllers?' for #<__Some__Controller:_____>
```

Why does this happen and how can I solve it? I couldn't find any solutions online and since it is my first rails application I'm not so familiar with it yet.

Comment: Hi @gkaran89! Try moving all that configuration to your `RegistrationsController` and remove thar `if: :devise_controllers?` and let's see if the error disappears.

Comment: Thank you that worked. But still I cannot get why the :devise_controllers? is not defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a typo: the name of the helper is `:devise_controller?`, notice the extra "s" you have there: [rubydoc reference](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#devise_controller%3F-instance_method)

Comment: As I said, total noob :P Thanks!

Comment: It happens to everyone... :)