# Rails 4.2 Devise custom controller and Views for a custom user dbms

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Hi I have a problem with the devise, I made a custom view for the users , so that I can have a username and a full name like so

[image]

as you can see i have adjusted the custom view for the devise user signup, but the problem is that when i sign up and i check the console it gives me this in the console

[image]

This is what I did for the routes

[image]

now I tried to logout but i cant seem to do so like the image

[image]

Any help will really be appreciated, for the with and how to properly customize devise with some custom / added attributes into the user database.

Comment: add extra fields to devise http://jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html

Comment: when you are passing username and fullname from form you need to add them in strong params list. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297797/add-custom-field-column-to-devise-with-rails-4