# Can't add custom fields to Devise model in Ruby on Rails. Private method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Generated User model using Devise gem.

Trying to add 'username' attribute.

Followed official documentation, now my ApplicationController looks like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:username])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
  end

end
```

When I try to go to account update page I get following error:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#edit

private method `permit' called for #Devise::ParameterSanitizer:0x007f13396cf180>
```

What can be wrong in here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20760338/1143732), you can also do the following:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in)        << :username
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up)        << :username
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :username
end
```

Comment: Why @Saiqul Haq answer not worked , while this one did . As i'm seeing that both have the same logical output (making the assumption just by looking at the codes

Answer (score 18):

## Below answer might be outdated for you, so please [read the source code instead HERE](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb)

---

First thing that you should aware is your devise version
so check the installed version on your rails app by do following command:

```
cat Gemfile.lock | grep devise
```

it shows which devise version that installed on your rails app, it's like:

```
devise (= 3.1.0)
```

---

If your devise's version is >= 4.0.0.rc1

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user_params|
    user_params.permit({ roles: [] }, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

---

for version < 4.0.0.rc1

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in)        << :username
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up)        << :username
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :username
end
```

Comment: Not sure how `{ roles: [] }` is any use in this answer.... That was just an example on the GitHub devise readme.md if checkboxes are being used since they are not strong params...