# Ruby on rails: can't save profile model associated with Devise user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, model-associations

I have Devise `user` model and associated `profile` model. Here it is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_one :profile, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
  before_create :build_profile
end
```

Profile model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Next, I include profile fields in default Devise view:

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>

    <%= f.fields_for :profile do |profile_form| %>

        <div class="field">
          <%= profile_form.label :username %><br />
          <%= profile_form.text_field :username %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <%= profile_form.label :address %><br />
          <%= profile_form.text_field :address %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <%= profile_form.label :pin %><br />
          <%= profile_form.text_field :pin %>
        </div>
    <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete %></p>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

Now, when I update form, Devise field is updated, but profile fields - not. If I trying to update profile thru rails console, everything works just great.

```
u = User.find_by(id: 2)
u.profile.pin = 123
u.save
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Custom Field/Column to Devise with Rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297797/add-custom-field-column-to-devise-with-rails-4)

Comment: You need to need to override the devise strong parameters method so that the your extra parameters are allowed for mass assignment. See the question above.

Comment: @max you just saved my night and my dreams! Thank you SO much!

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Just override Devise permitted_parameters in ApplicationController like this:

```
before_action :configure_devise_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected
def configure_devise_permitted_parameters
    registration_params = [:email, :password, :password_confirmation, profile_attributes: [:username, :address, :pin]]

    if params[:action] == 'update'
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) {
          |u| u.permit(registration_params << :current_password)
      }
    elsif params[:action] == 'create'
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {
          |u| u.permit(registration_params)
      }
    end
  end
```

Thanks @max for answer.